# IOS scroll gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c

i made this sliding gallery in my app:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(photoTap:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

int pageCount = 3;
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                          0,
                                                                          360,
                                                                          200)];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageCount*scrollView.bounds.size.width ,
                                    scrollView.bounds.size.height);

[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

CGRect viewsize = scrollView.bounds;

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:viewsize];
[image setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"]];
image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[scrollView addSubview:image];


viewsize = CGRectOffset(viewsize, scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);

UIImageView *image2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:viewsize];
[image2 setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"02.png"]];
image2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[scrollView addSubview:image2];

- (void)photoTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer{
}
```

How can i detect which photo is tapped in my scrollview?
I have tried to add gesture recognizer to the image but only the last one works.
Any suggestion? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can add gesture recognizer to the scrollview, after detecting the tap, detect its location on the UIScrollView's content by adding the coordinates of the tap to the content offset. When you have this coordinate i think that detecting the image is not a problem.

Comment: The gesture recognizer is already being added to the scrollview.